# Insert a number of unknown length at random places in a string in PHP

Tags: php

I create a random string of a given length with the function below:

```php
function generateRandomString($length) {
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[random_int(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

This gives me a result of e.g. `aBcDEFghIJKlmNo` when giving it 15 as length.

Now I also have a variable number that can go from say 1 to 10.000.000. Let us say the number is 12.345 for simplicity, but the solution needs to work for any number in the range.

I need a function that takes this number 12.345 and puts the numbers **consecutively** into the string `aBcDEFghIJKlmNo` at random places, giving a result of e.g. 'a**1**BcD**23**EFg**4**hIJ**5**KlmNo'.

```php
function placeNumberInString($string, $number){
    $new_string = '';

    // I can't figure out what to do here...

    return $new_string;
}

$result = placeNumberInString(aBcDEFghIJKlmNo, 12345);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a single iteration of a [classic riffle shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riffle_shuffle_permutation) between a `aBcDEFghIJKlmNo` stack and a `12345` stack. Use `str_split()` to split each stack into arrays, so that you have this:

```
$one = ["a","B","c","D","E","F","g","h","I","J","K","l","m","N","o"];
$two = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
```

Then implement the shuffle on those two arrays:

- Pick a stack randomly, but weighted by the number of elements in that stack. This ensures you get an even distribution when the stacks are different sizes.
- Take one element from the front/top of that stack and add it to the end of the new merged stack.
- Repeat until there are no elements left.

Something like:

```
function riffle(string $one, string $two): string
{
  $new = '';
  $tot = strlen($one . $two);
  $from = [str_split($one), str_split($two)];
  while (array_filter($from)) {
    $new .= array_shift($from[lcg_value() <= count($from[0]) / $tot-- ? 0 : 1]);
  }
  return $new;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string at random index starting at the last index and insert the number

```php
function placeNumberInString($string, $number){
    $new_string = $string;
    
    $numberArray = str_split((string)$number);
    
    $index = 0;

    foreach ($numberArray as $value) {
        $index = rand($index, strlen($new_string));
        
        $begin = substr($new_string, 0, $index + 1);
        $end = substr($new_string, $index + 1);
        
        $new_string = $begin . $value . $end;
    }

    return $new_string;
}

$result = placeNumberInString("aBcDEFghIJKlmNo", 12345);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Close but it doesn't put the number consecutively  in the string, 12345 needs to be at random places in the string but in order, as given by the example. This is a good start for me though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the order of the digits in the number, you could just build up the new string a bit at a time.

```
$numberAsString = (string) $number;
$stringLength = strlen($string);
$numberStringLength = strlen($numberAsString);

$s = 0;
$i = 0;
while (($s < $stringLength) && ($i < $numberStringLength)) {
    if (random_int(0, 1)) {
        $newString .= $string[$s];
        $s++;
    } else {
        $newString .= $numberAsString[$i];
        $i++;
    }
}
if ($s < $stringLength) {
    $newString .= substr($string, $s);
} else {
    $newString .= substr($numberAsString, $i);
}
```